# How does gcc decide the wide character set when calling `mbtowc()`?

Tags: c, character-encoding, multibyte, widechar

According to the gcc manual, the option [`-fwide-exec-charset`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) specifies the wide character set of wide string and character constants at compile time.

But what is the wide character set when converting a multi-byte character to a wide character by calling `mbtowc()` at run time? The [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/mbtowc.html) says that the character set of multi-byte characters is determined by the LC_CTYPE category of the current locale, but says nothing about the wide character set.  I don't have a C standard at hand now so I don't know what the C standard says about this.

Does the gcc option `-fwide-exec-charset` determine the wide character set used by `mbtowc()`, just as it does at compile time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: the character set used for wide strings gets determined by the characteristics of `wchar_t` known at compile time. As `mbtowc` is a library function, this happens when libc is being built.

`mbtowc` reads a single character from a string encoded in an external charset and writes it out to a `wchar_t` value able to represent any character. Likewise, `mbstowcs` converts an externally encoded C string into a simple array of `wchar_t`. From the system's point of view, it doesn't make sense to specify the "charset" of the resulting wide character/string, because changing its output encoding in any way would break the usage of the resulting wide string as array of `wchar_t`.

You can *describe* `mbstowcs` as producing fixed-width Unicode encodings such as UCS-2 or UCS-4 (or more precisely UTF-16 or UTF-32) if the wide chars correspond to ISO 10646 code points, and depending on the width of `wchar_t`. You can also describe it as little-endian or big-endian depending on your the endianness of the processor's representation of `wchar_t`. But those are properties of the platform, which you can't change at run-time any more than you can change endianness, or ASCII to EBCDIC.

`-fwide-exec-charset` serves to explicitly specify to the compiler the charset that corresponds to the internal representation of array-of-`wchar_t`. This is useful when it differs from the representation the compiler would normally generate (because you are crosscompiling, or because the compiler was misconfigured). This is why the manual goes on to warn that "you will have problems with encodings that do not fit exactly in `wchar_t`."

Comment: According to the [c preprocessor manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Character-sets.html#Character-sets), the c preprocessor does not see the execution character set but the source character set. So `-fwide-exec-charset` will not affect the preprocessor.

Comment: You mentioned cross-compiling, which I think may be the reason why `-fwide-exec-charset` exists. The last paragraph of section 2.1.1 of the book ["C: A Reference Manual"](http://www.amazon.com/Reference-Manual-Samuel-P-Harbison/dp/013089592X) mentions the cross-compiling too when explaining that the source and execution character set may be different. But there is still a problem: if I set `-fwide-exec-charset`, then the execution character set of a wide string constant may be different from that of a string transformed by calling `mbtowc()`. So I don't see much use of this option.

Comment: @wbb It may be different only if you specify the wrong charset. It's not supposed to be something you customize, it's a last resort for fixing the incompatibility between the strings generated by the compiler and those generated in runtime by libc. `-fwide-exec-charset` should not be necessary when things are correctly configured (again, barring cross-compilation where such mismatches are often seen).